# If the value of $\log 2 = 0.3010$, then the number of zeroes after the decimal point till the first non-zero digit in $0.16^{20}$ is?

Tags: logarithms, contest-math

I had noted down this statement in my notebook which says that "If $-n$ is the characteristic of $\log_{10}y$, then the number of zeroes between the decimal and the first significant digit after the decimal is $n-1$".

$\log(0.16^{20})= -15.92$ and as per the above statement the answer should be $14$ but the correct answer has been given as $15$. I am not able to get what I have done wrong. Is my theory wrong? What is the correct method?

Comment: Shortcut: (not worth making into an answer): $$10^{-(1.92)} \approx 0.012.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you write a positive number in scientific notation as $y=x\cdot 10^n$ where $1\leq x<10$ then

$$\log_{10}(y)=\log_{10}(x\cdot 10^n)=\log_{10}(x)+n$$
Now since $1\leq x<10$ you get that $0\leq \log_{10}(x)<1$ is positive and $<1$ and thus this accounts for the frational part, whereas $n$ accounts for the integer part.

In your case you now have
$$\log_{10}(0.16^{20})=-15.92=-0.92+(-15)=0.08+(-16).$$
But as we said before, the fractional part must be positive, thus the second way is the correct one. Consequently you now know that $n=16$ and hence you have $15$ digits.